# react component not rerendering on set state with a 2d array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a Conway's game of life on react and I cannot get the component to rerender every time I reset the state of the 2d array I am using to represent the world.

It does rerender when I call the function that changes the state with a start button. However, the function calls itself with a setTimeout, and though it keeps running because I have checked it with a console.log, it does not rerender the component until I stop and restart the loop (I'm using the same button for both stopping and starting).

This is the function I am using for looping through generations:

```
const passTime = () => {

if (!runningRef.current) return

const newWorld = cloneWorld(world)

for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

  for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {

    let neighbours = 0
    neighbourhood.forEach(([x, y]) => {
      const newI = i + x
      const newJ = j + y
      if (newI >= 0 && newI < numRows && newJ >= 0 && newJ < numCols) {
        neighbours += world[newI][newJ]
      }
    })

    if (neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3) newWorld[i][j] = 0

    if (world[i][j] === 0 && neighbours === 3) newWorld[i][j] = 1
  }
}
setWorld(newWorld)
setState(!state)

console.log(runningRef.current)
setTimeout(passTime, 100)
}
```

And these are the functions I use for both creating and cloning the grid:

```
export const generateWorld = (rows: number, columns: number): World => {
const grid: World = []

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    grid.push(Array.from(Array(columns), () => 0))
  }
  return grid
}

export const cloneWorld = (world: World): World => {
  const clonedWorld: World = []

  for (let i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
    clonedWorld[i] = [...world[i]]
  }
  return clonedWorld
}
```

Comment: could you convert your code to the snippet so that it's runnable?

Comment: Do you mean the whole app, or just the functions above?

Comment: relevant code, pls

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I'm quite new here. I'm trying to create the snippet but, being typescript code, it seems some functionalities don't work, as the export statements. 
Am I missing something? I have added the react version and the babel support for the jsx code, but I do not see any option to use the typescript compiler.